# Elasticsearch Integration in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, search, model-view-controller, elasticsearch

Is there anyone knows how to integrate the spring mvc and elastisearch?
I want to implement a web page like general web site(google,yahoo searcg engine)
Is there any tutorial or sample code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the Spring Data Elasticsearch [project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch).

[Here](https://github.com/BioMedCentralLtd/spring-data-elasticsearch-sample-application) is a sample application.

Comment: But this project is not integrate the spring mvc

Comment: What do you mean? It's part of the Spring Data project which integrates seamlessly with Spring. What more integration do you need?

Comment: I want some web showcase or tutorial with the elasticsearch in MVC(How to write the jsp and controller?) not only the spring data application. Because I am a newbee in spring, I want to use search some data from elasticsearch by using webpage like google search. Thanks~

Comment: You will have to pull together various tutorials to find what you are asking for.