# How to integrate elasticSearch with spring?

Tags: spring, elasticsearch

How to integrate elasticSearch with spring? 
Any tutorial and example code will be very helpful.
These are part of my spring project maven dependencies, we don't use spring-boot, I already read some of the tutorials that integrate elasticSearch  with spring-boot, but it doesn't help.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springFramework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springFramework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springFramework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springSecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springSecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>${springSecurityOauth2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${springData.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Searching for 'integrate elasticsearchwith spring' provided a lot of examples, documentation and tutorials. Which of those have you tried and what problems do you still have?

Comment: I am using spring-context-support 2.1.4.RELEASE now, there is another problem, I can't update a mapping for existing fields in elasticSearch using ElasticsearchOperations object. I want to know if mysql table changed I have to update my elasticSearch mapping ,but I don't want to re-create the index and import the data again, Is there any better solution  for these rather than update the mapping?

Comment: If you have a new problem, you should ask it as a new question. I'd strongly recommend reading the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), to learn how to ask questions on Stack Overflow that will guarantee you good answers; it's not exactly the same as other forums.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use Elasticsearch with

- the Spring-Data project for [Elasticsearch](https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-elasticsearch/) which is also [documented](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/) and has an existing [API defintion](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/3.0.0.M4/api/) ([Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-elasticsearch))
- the Elasticsearch [Java API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/5.5/index.html) which is well documented and where you can find several code snippets in their documentation as well as the internet general - though it is pretty straight forward. You may use this [blog post](https://dzone.com/articles/elasticsearch-java-api) for an introduction ([Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch),[also see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077887/elasticsearch-integration-in-spring-mvc?rq=1))
- or the Elasticsearch REST API which is also well [documented](https://dzone.com/articles/elasticsearch-java-api).

In my previous project, I built a search engine using Elasticsearch. In my case I implemented a search application which utilized its Java API, while my project was built with Spring Boot.